# Error trying to print Collection variable by index

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql

Can anyone identify what is wrong with the following code. specifically the first dbms_output line. The second one prints fine. But first one gives this error:

**Error at line 2
ORA-06550: line 15, column 53:
PLS-00201: identifier 'MYCOLL' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 15, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored**

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c1
   IS
      SELECT sub_provider_address_id sub_id, phone, extension
        FROM sub_provider_address;

   TYPE coll_type IS TABLE OF c1%ROWTYPE;
   my_coll   coll_type;
BEGIN
   OPEN c1;

   FETCH c1
   BULK COLLECT INTO my_coll;

dbms_output.put_line(' my_coll first row id has '|| mycoll(1).phone );
dbms_output.put_line(' my_coll now has '|| my_coll.last );

END;
```

Comment: Don't forget to close your cursor

Comment: it's my_coll not mycoll! Problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring the variable as `my_coll`:

```
my_coll   coll_type;
```

And on the line that's erroring you're referring to it as `mycoll`:

```
dbms_output.put_line(' my_coll first row id has '|| mycoll(1).phone );
```

So you're just missing an underscore, and it should be:

```
dbms_output.put_line(' my_coll first row id has '|| my_coll(1).phone );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `coll_type` is not an associated array type. 
you have to use something like this:

```
TYPE coll_type IS TABLE OF c1%ROWTYPE index by pls_integer;
```

Use this as an example:

```
declare
  cursor c1 is
    select 1 id from dual
  ;
  type coll_type is table of c1%ROWTYPE index by pls_integer;
  l_coll_type coll_type;
begin
  open c1;
  fetch c1 bulk collect into l_coll_type;
  close c1;
  dbms_output.put_line('Output:' || l_coll_type(1).id);
end;

Output:1
```

Comment: I added the "index by pls_integer" in declaration as you suggested. That did not still help. The line to print mycoll(i).phone still results in the same error.

Comment: is your variable `i` in `mycoll(i).phone` declared?